# Getting null values in Postman. How to fix it?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, postman

I'm trying to test this method:

```
public HttpResponseMessage Get()
{
    Orders orders = new Orders();
    var result = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, orders);

    if (orders.DateOrder > DateTime.Now || orders.DateOrder == null)
    {
        result.Content = new StringContent(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(db.Orders.ToList()));
       result.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/json");
    }
    return result;
}
```

But I get strange null values instead of the ones in the table. How to fix it? Maybe it's because i use Web API in my MVC project instead of сreating a new Web API project? I hope you can help me.

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jT93u.jpg)

Comment: Please provide [mcve].

Comment: Did you debug to check whether the Orders have Values filled in them

Comment: I have an Orders table with my values, but Postman outputs null values instead

Comment: forget about postman. debug your own endpoint and see what's going on first

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is you set `var result = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, orders);`

too early.

orders is a empty object so it has the values you get from your controller.

You can check the `if` first and only after create the response object.